# How to create an index?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, social-science

Assume a situation where countries are obliged to report to an international organization each year. For each year, there are a number of reports that have been received, and number of reports that have not been received. These numbers can really vary from year to year -- it all depends on the current situation of states.

I want to create an index indicating states' reporting behavior – that is, how well they comply with their reporting obligations. 
I make no distinction between reports, all are equally important. The most important thing to measure is states' reporting behavior for each year. The idea is to use this index/score in a regression analysis (for example OLS).

See an example below:

```
Country     Year    Requested   Received    Non-received    Index
A           2000       10          8            2             ?
B           2000       7           4            3   
C           2000       12          2            10  
A           2001       14          10           4   
B           2001       2           0            2   
C           2001       10          10           0
```

I thought of dividing the number of received (or non-received) reports to get a ratio (or percentage). However, it seems that these things are much more complicated than this.

I appreciate all suggestions and help with constructing this index.

Comment: Do you want your index to represent reporting behaviour each year (i.e., one score per year per country), or overall (one score per country)?

Comment: @Ian_Fin Hi – one score per year and country

Comment: What is it that's "much more complicated" then? For each year in each country you have the number of reports requested and the number received. There's no information that you present besides these that you need to take into account.